# Low disk space warning messages in RHEL

Tags: linux

Can someone please tell me in which log file linux logs the low disk space warnings. I checked all files in /var/log but couldn't find, also google is giving me scripts for sending email alerts on specific events :-(. 
We are fetching all our servers log files into our monitoring tool, but we dont see low disk space warnings there.
Regards,
Balaji.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the OS does not provide these types of alerts.

If you want some form of disk space alerting, you'll either need to script it or use a tool like [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit) to report on system health. It reports to syslog.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any messages because they are not generated automagicaly by the OS. You will have to put something in place and set up alerting yourself.

Perhaps use one of those scripts you found and amend it to write a message to the logs (use [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html)) or even look at your monitoring tool and see if it can do this already.

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if this is where your problem is but something a lot of people don't check with low disk space warnings is whether or not there are unused packages that can be removed, they chew up a lot of space. On Ubuntu this just means running

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Not sure what distro you have but worth checking to see if that is your problem or not.

Comment: "Not sure what distro you have" -- the "RHEL" in the question title should have been a clue.

Comment: Oops, my bad mistake